# Why is extending an extended view not working in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to create a modal view and have a base class that all modals need and then extending it for more specific functionality.

```
    PlanSource.Modal = Ember.View.extend({
        isShowing: false,
        hide: function() {
            this.set("isShowing", false);
        },
        close: function() {
            this.set("isShowing", false);
        },
        show: function() {
            this.set("isShowing", true);
        }
    });
    PlanSource.AddJobModal = PlanSource.Modal.extend({
        templateName: "modals/add_job",
        createJob: function() {
            var container = $("#new-job-name"),
                name = container.val();
            if (!name || name == "") return;
            var job = PlanSource.Job.createRecord({
                "name": name
            });
            job.save();
            container.val("");
            this.send("hide");
        }
    });
```

I render it with

```
{{view PlanSource.AddJobModal}}
```

And have the view template

```
<a class="button button-green" {{action show target=view}}>+ Add Job</a>
{{#if view.isShowing}}
<div class="modal-wrapper">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="dialog box box-border">
        <div class="header">
            <p class="title">Enter a job name.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <p>Enter a name for your new job.</p>
            <input type="text" id="new-job-name" placeholder="Job name">
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="buttons">
                <a class="button button-blue" {{action createJob target=view}} >Create</a>
                <a class="button" {{action close target=view}}>No</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{/if}}
```

The problem is that when I click the button on the modal dialog, it gives me an "action createJob" can not be found.  Am I extending the objects incorrectly because it works if I put the createJob in the base Modal class.

## Fixed

There was an issue somewhere else in my code.  The name got copied and so it was redefining it and making the method not exist.